# Leaflet Legend toggle

Tags: button, leaflet, legend

I'm trying to create a legend which should work like on this site but I can't get it to work...

(press the 'i' button)

http://mtbmap.no/#6/63.400/10.390

I tried popup with easy button plugin but it shows up on the middle of the screen. I would like to have toggle like on mtbmap.

Here's my working site

http://pomorskieszlaki.pl/index.html#9/54.2516/18.3774/osm-rowerowe-piesze-ddr

Any chance to point me the right way?

Thanks a lot. I'm still a newbie with JS...

Comment: Why do you have two "i" buttons here?Shouldn't a click on one "i" button just toggle the legend `div` you want to?

Comment: Sorry, these other buttons are just my tryouts. I left the button that should be working but it's not at the moment. Here's a code:

http://pomorskieszlaki.pl/js/leaflet-info.js

What is wrong in there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking to add this feature to your map, there is a way.

You can use `makeIcon( with your attributes)` to embed, size and attach a graphic icon, you can also set the distance away from the icon that this popu opens up.

Then you can `addPopup(with your attributes)` to add a popUp box to that icon which is editable as any other popup would be.